# Define routing value in app.UseExceptionHandler

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have a Multilanguage project for which all urls include the language code to set the current language. The URLs have the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/en-US/Page
```

In Configure method of the Startup.cs I have the following lines:

```cs
app.UseExceptionHandler("/en-US/Error");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/en-US/error/{0}");
```

For both lines I want to change the "en-US" value with a definition for the lang routing value so that depending on the currently selected language, the equivalent error page will use the user's selected language.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing the repo on Github and see what those extension methods do. If they have access to the request context when called then it should provide you access to the route to be able to modify it to your liking. All in all you would need to customize it yourself

Comment: Found where the path is set for exception handler middleware here https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/3a868d87a2458fd025ca71e2538b3a72f67c7c50/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L60

Comment: You could always copy the code and make your own custom middle ware to perform the desired behavior.

Comment: I think this should be supported by default because routing is a basic feature for ASP.NET Core. I will try to change the code and use it in my project. Thank you for the information.

Comment: If what you build works out well you can always submit it back to them as a pull request and then it will be supported by default.